# not able to validate text box using java script

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

my input text box source like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtDepCode" runat="server" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
```

and my javascript function like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function confirm_user() {
        var userPass = document.getElementById('TxtDepCode');
        alert(userPass)
        if (userPass=''){
        alert("value is blank")
        }
        if (confirm("Department already available, would you like to update ?") == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

in submit button click i want to check wethar corresponding text is empty or not
my submit button click event like this:

Comment: try userPass.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userPass = document.getElementById('TxtDepCode').value;
```

Or

```
var userPass = document.getElementById('<%=TxtDepCode.ClientID%>').value;
```

Modify the first line of function to get value of textbox as above

```
if (userPass==''){
```

Modify `if` as above

Comment: Modify your if statement also as given in modified answer

Comment: var userPass = document.getElementById('TxtDepCode').value;
        alert(userPass)

Comment: i am just cheking wethar i am getting my input value in that variable..but not getting

Comment: now got it sir.if you dont mind y i want to add clientID

Comment: No need if you got it. You need to use client id in case textbox is nested in some other control.

Comment: @user3262364 Make sure you return false if user is blank

Answer (score 1):

The crucial issues in the code are as follows:

1. Get the value of the password and not the element:

   `var userPass = document.getElementById('TxtDepCode').value;`
2. Change the if to [== or ===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) instead of single =

   `if (userPass == '') {`
3. You are using `<asp:TextBox>` that can have a dynamic ID. Therefore you should get the dynamic ID using .NET's `ClientID`:

   `var userPass = document.getElementById('<% =TxtDepCode.ClientID %>').value;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false if value is blank too

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function confirm_user() {
    var userPass = document.getElementById('TxtDepCode');
    alert(userPass)
    if (userPass.value == ''){ // == not = and userPass.value
    alert("value is blank");
    return false; // Need to stop the function
    }
    if (confirm("Department already available, would you like to update ?") == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```